# Resource Assemblies for Different Resolutions on Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, localization, compact-framework, resolution

I've got a .NET Compact Framework application, which targets a number of different handheld devices, with varying resolutions. At the moment, I've built it for one resolution, and then have checks on loading forms to see what resolution the current device has and then I manually load images for that resolution, handle scaling etc. Obviously this is far from ideal.

Visual Studio has some nice localisation features, including separate images and text for other locales, but does it have anything similar for different resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Orientation Aware Control](http://www1.orientationaware.net/home.html) was created for just this purpose.

It allows you to specify different layouts for a form based for different screen sizes, orientations and resolutions. The layout is automatically applied at run and design time.